# Transformer percentage impedance

Tags: transformer

In the figure shown below, the 13.8kV is it the internal transformer voltage or is it the voltage at the terminal of the transformer i.e. if I measured the transformer terminals I would get a 13.8kV reading?

[image]

Comment: It depends on the loading. If running at full load it should likely be 13.8 kV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to say that utility power transformers are nameplated with the no-load voltage ratings.

> IEEE Std C57.12.01™-2020 -- 5.5.2 Voltage rating -- The voltage rating at no load shall be based on the turns ratio. The transformer terminal voltage is subject to the effect of magnitude of load and load power factor.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following transformer equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6HnL9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The image you posted in the question is a simplified schematic. I believe you want to describe this scheme when you say 'internal transformer voltage'. As @Andy aka pointed in the comment, the voltage measured there depends on the load you have in the secondary side.
If there is no load, the voltage will work according to the turns (and voltage) ratio of the transformer.
If there is some load, the secondary voltage will depend on the amout of load and it's power factor.